# What's "Hosting Content with Apple "

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

[image]

When I create In-App purchase in iTunes Connect . I found this option "Hosting Content with Apple" I did't see it before. What should I do , I should select Yes or NO. I don't understand. I think this option come after WWDC.

Comment: I think you'd better accept @AmitShah's answer. :)

Answer (score 71):

This is a new feature with iOS 6, you can have apple host your content, such as images and videos. 
If you are looking to support anything below iOS6, then you should select no (assuming you have content that needs to be hosted), if your in app purchase does not need to download anything, then just select no.

Comment: Is there anyway for uploading the content other than iOS6.Then how the developers used to do at before iOS 6 ?Even I got stuck on this point for couple of days.

Comment: You mean use this feature for devices below iOS 6? Can't be done I'm afraid, you'd have to use your own web server, and host the content on there.

Comment: @AmitShah It gives me error when I try to archive/create the package contains the PDF content.What would be reason of this error : The package contains an executable at 'Contents/gateofzion.pdf'. Can you help with to get rid of this error.

Comment: Does "Hosted contents in Apple" allow free contents?

Comment: I don't believe it does, just for In-app purchases.

Comment: Can you disable it after creating the IAP?